# flutter - error when running in app purchase plugin : "MissingPluginException for BillingClient"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I try to run example scripts from flutter official's **example of in-app-purchase plugin**, located [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/in_app_purchase/example/lib). I added those example to one of my screen of my apps.

However, starting from my apps screento in-app-purchase's example screen,i got below error :

> E/flutter ( 2557): **[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method BillingClient#startConnection(BillingClientStateListener) on channel plugins.flutter.io/in_app_purchase)**
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:7)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): 
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #1      BillingClient.startConnection (package:in_app_purchase/src/billing_client_wrappers/billing_client_wrapper.dart:89:62)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): 
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #2      GooglePlayConnection._connect (package:in_app_purchase/src/in_app_purchase/google_play_connection.dart:166:21)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #3      new GooglePlayConnection._ (package:in_app_purchase/src/in_app_purchase/google_play_connection.dart:27:20)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #4      GooglePlayConnection._getOrCreateInstance (package:in_app_purchase/src/in_app_purchase/google_play_connection.dart:161:38)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #5      GooglePlayConnection.instance (package:in_app_purchase/src/in_app_purchase/google_play_connection.dart:32:47)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #6      InAppPurchaseConnection._getOrCreateInstance (package:in_app_purchase/src/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase_connection.dart:225:40)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #7      InAppPurchaseConnection.instance (package:in_app_purchase/src/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase_connection.dart:216:50)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #8      new _PermanentDonorScreenState (package:zipediaapps/src/ui/sadaqah/permanent_donor_screen.dart:79:71)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #9      PermanentDonorScreen.createState (package:zipediaapps/src/ui/sadaqah/permanent_donor_screen.dart:52:47)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #10     new StatefulElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3989:25)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #11     StatefulWidget.createElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:802:38)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3082:40)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #14     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #17     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #19     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #20     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #29     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #30     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #32     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #33     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #35     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #36     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #37     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #38     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   E/flutter ( 2557): #40     E
>   I/flutter ( 2557): 0

about flutter doctor, here're the status:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Mac OS X 10.14.1 18B75, locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.3 at /Users/anunixercoder/development/flutter
    • Framework revision b712a172f9 (3 weeks ago), 2019-07-09 13:14:38 -0700
    • Engine revision 54ad777fd2
    • Dart version 2.4.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/anunixercode/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.2

[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 31.2.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Any Idea to Solve ?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: have you tried a "flutter clean" and then try again. I've found that helps sometimes with similar platform errors